# Find full JSON body in file

Tags: python, json, file

I'm trying to find a full (i.e. exact) json body in a log file. Let's say we have body like:

```
{
  "superObject": {
        "object": {
          "property1": 0,
          "property2": "",
          "property3": False
        }
      },
      "superProperty1": "abcd",
      "superProperty2": 4321
    }
```

and a .txt file, named log_test.txt and it contains:

```
bla
bla 
bla 
POST   {
  "superObject": {
        "object": {
          "property1": 0,
          "property2": "",
          "property3": False
        }
      },
      "superProperty1": "abcd",
      "superProperty2": 4321
    }
bla bla
bla
```

I am trying to find all the body in log_text.txt.

#### What I tried

First option was to make body as str(dict), split it by lines and the every req line find line by line in file:

```
import sys
import json
import string

def test():        
    req = {
      "superObject": {
        "object": {
          "property1": 0,
          "property2": "",
          "property3": False
        }
      },
      "superProperty1": "abcd",
      "superProperty2": 4321
    }

    for req_line in str(req).splitlines(True):
        with open("C://log_test.txt", 'r') as log:
            for line in log:
                if req_line in line:
                    print req_line + " It's there!!!"
                    log.close()
                    return
        log.close()            
        print "It's NOT there!!!"
        raise Exception("String '" + req_line + "' does not exist")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

No luck though, it didn't split it, and tried to search all the body in every line, the same if to `for req_line in str(req).split("\n")`.

Second option was to dump dict via python's json lib and also look for line by line:
`for req_line in json.dumps(req).splitlines(True):` looks for all body in each file's line, `for req_line in json.dumps(req):` looks for first { finds it and returns, i.e. passes just first line. I tried to search similar problem, but found just solutions similar to my first option than didn't work, as I wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with option one is that *str(req)* doesn't insert new lines into the string. You could try to load the log file and then normalize the log file and the req string. I tested it with the following and it found the body:

```js
import sys
import json
import string

def test():        
    req = {
        "superObject": {
            "object": {
                "property1": 0,
                "property2": "",
                "property3": False
            }
        },
        "superProperty1": "abcd",
        "superProperty2": 4321
      }

    with open("./log_test.txt", 'r') as log:
        log_string = ''
        for line in log:
            log_string = log_string + line.replace('\n', '').replace(' ', '')
        req_string = str(req).replace('\n', '').replace(' ', '').replace("'", '"')
        log.close()            
        if req_string in log_string:
            print str(req) + " It's there!!!"
        else:
            print "It's NOT there!!!"
            raise Exception("String '" + str(req) + "' does not exist")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

Comment: tried your code, got     raise Exception("String '" + str(req) + "' does not exist")
Exception: String '{'extensions': {'object': {'property1': 0, 'property2': '', '
property3': False}}, 'superProperty1': 'abcd', 'superProperty2': 4321}' does not
 exist  but thanks anyway :) maybe it's related to line-breaks parsing differences between windows (i'm on it) and linux?

Comment: Line endings should be the problem. You can try to add a .replace('\r', '') along with the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you only want to find that json body (exact) in one txt file like log_test.txt, it's simple. Following your previous code:

```
req = '''{
  "superObject": {
        "object": {
          "property1": 0,
          "property2": "",
          "property3": False
        }
      },
      "superProperty1": "abcd",
      "superProperty2": 4321
    }'''


def test():

    with open("C://log_test.txt", 'r') as log:
        _file = log.read()
        if req in _file:
            print req + " It's there!!!"
            log.close()
            return
        log.close()
        print "It's NOT there!!!"
        raise Exception("String '" + req + "' does not exist")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

It works for your example. If you'd like parser a full JSON file, take a look at [Parsing values from a JSON file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835559/parsing-values-from-a-json-file-in-python)

Comment: hm, tried exact your code, got:     raise Exception("String '" + req + "' does not exist")
Exception: String '{
      "extensions": {
        "object": {
          "property1": 0,
          "property2": "",
          "property3": False
        }
      },
      "superProperty1": "abcd",
      "superProperty2": 4321
    }' does not exist, but thanks anyway :)

Comment: sorry, the error of course is     raise Exception("String '" + req + "' does not exist")
Exception: String '{
      "superObject": {
        "object": {
          "property1": 0,
          "property2": "",
          "property3": False
        }
      },
      "superProperty1": "abcd",
      "superProperty2": 4321
    }' does not exist